# Regex in Oracle- put a string after each 5 characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have to put a string after every 5 characters in a given string (varchar2).
Given string can have different length.
I already solved it by a loop using substrings.
Is there any way i could reach the goal using REGEXP in Oracle DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace every 5 characters with those 5 characters followed by another string. For example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABCDE12345FGHIJ67890KL', '(.{5})', '\1*') FROM DUAL
```

Output:

```
ABCDE*12345*FGHIJ*67890*KL
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c957f79485892f670f6e7aa090c21de)